# Emulator does not persist its permissions for API 23

Tags: android, emulation

I used to test with the Android Studio emulator and go through permissions for api=23, I did allow for all permissions and they would persist for the next run, this is what was expected and it worked all along.  Lately I created a new AVD, it started to behave differently; I get all the permissions dialog and answer Allow to all of them, but on my next session, those permissions are being asked again.  Is there a setting to **prevent** the emulator to wipe everything each time? And why is it doing this all of a sudden?

Comment: Plz provide more detail abt emulator.

Comment: I have been using 2 different emulators and they do the same thing, test on actual device works perfectly (permissions persist correctly). running the latest studio, latest haxm, tried gennymotion and decided not to go with it.